# 左右のDrawerLayoutが重なる

Tags: android

現在アクションバーの左端と右端にボタンがあり、左端のボタンを押すと左からListViewのDrawerLayoutが出てきて、右端のボタンを押すと右からも同じくListViewのDrawerLayoutが出てくるというような画面を作っています。しかし、左端のボタンを押してからDrawerLayoutが出きらないうちに右端のボタンを押すと、左右のDrawerLayoutが重なって画面に表示されてしまいます。ちなみに左側のDrawerLayoutが出きった状態で右側のボタンを押すと、右側のDrawerLayoutが表示されるとともに左側のDrawerLayoutは閉じます。下記にボタンが押された時のDrawerLayoutに関する処理のコードを記載します。この重なりを回避するにはどこを修正すればよろしいでしょうか？すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)){
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                }
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_drawer:
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)){
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                }else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isDrawerOpen()ではなくisDrawerVisible()で判断してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: isDrawerVisibleで判断したところ、ちゃんと片方のみのDrawerLayoutが表示されるようになりました！本当にありがとうございます！